# Changing or resetting password for mysql user

Tags: mysql, sql

how would look a simple query for Mysql database for resetting passwords

I have a example code of my, but it doesn't work and I'm not sure how to make it work

```
SELECT `User`, `Host`, Length(`Password`) FROM mysql.user
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password = PASSWORD('password') WHERE user = 'username';
```

and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to select; only update.

```
update mysql.user set password=PASSWORD("NEW-PASSWORD-HERE") where User='USER';
```

Your problem may stem from the missing semi-colon after your select statement.

Comment: This is basically what the OP has, except you're assuming that `mysql` is the currently selected database, and the OP's explicitly forcing it to be that db.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'USER'@'HOST' = PASSWORD('PASSWORD');
```

Or, if you want to update the tables directly, don't forget to flush privileges.

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password = PASSWORD('PASSWORD') 
 WHERE user = 'USERNAME' AND Host='HOST';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Finally, there is a third way using GRANT:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'USER'@'HOST' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

---

Reference: [MySQL 5.7 Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-password.html)